# Kentico 10 - Custom action on page update

Tags: kentico

I am looking to perform a custom action when a content editor in Kentico 10 updates a page and it eventually gets published.

To be more specific we have a custom page type for products which also as an "Updated" checkbox allowing the editor to mark it as updated. When this happens (gets marked as updated) I would like to send an email out to users that have a registered interest in this product that it has been updated.

I was looking through the documentation and came across Global Events here: https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-DocumentEvents

I was wondering if using global events to intercept the save action when the editor updates the product is the way to go here or if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentico does n't have this functionality out of the box, but we can achieve this by writing Custom code for Global Event and a scheduler (if No.of mails is large)

**Recommended steps:**

1. Attach custom code to Global event handler while publish specific document publish after event

> public override void Init()
>           {
>               // Assigns custom handlers to the appropriate events
>               WorkflowEvents.Publish.After += new EventHandler(DocumentPublishCustomEvent);
>           }

2. In the custom code, if required page is published then make entries into custom table for email to be sent [This step is optional you can send mail from custom event handler directly if only few mails to be sent]

3.Implement custom scheduler to pick the user info from custom table and send email to user.

Note: Ideally you can use email Template for send emails

Answer (score 0):

Using Global events is one way of doing this, another way would be to use Kentico's Advanced workflow engine (If you have the EMS license):

https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-workflows/designing-advanced-workflows

You could create a custom workflow step and action which the editors would put the page into and which would send emails to interested people - https://docs.kentico.com/k10/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-workflows/designing-advanced-workflows/creating-custom-action-workflow-steps

If you do not have the EMS License, using Global events seems like the way to go, but I don't see the updated flag field as necessary, you could easily check in the global event handler if the product arrived at the "Published" workflow step in the basic workflow and then send the email to the interested parties.